# AS3 : 2 error 1061 and an error 1119

Tags: actionscript-3

Sorry ahead of time for french in my code or badly translated errors (idk what they are in english so Google translate). I'm working on a program at school to add all numbers, all even numbers or all odd numbers (different buttons) from an array (seperate file, called U2A2_Elements.as) and I'm getting multiple errors, I'm getting :

> 1061: Call for indexOf method might not be defined via the static int type reference at `entier = (entier.indexOf(entierSaisi));`
>
> 1119: Access to the length property can not be defined via the reference type static int" at `for (var i=entier; i entier.length; i++)`.
>
> 1061: Call for pop method might not be defined via the reference type static int" at `entier.pop();`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have no idea what to do with the code nor does the teacher or anyone else.

EDIT: Forgot to put the link to the code http://pastebin.com/5nyf3z7g

Comment: Please, show your relevant code.

Comment: Added the link, guess I had forgot. Sorry guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `supprimerFunction()` function, you forgot that your array is `mesEntiers` ( and not `entier` which is an `int` object ), so I think that you should write :

```
function supprimerFunction(event:MouseEvent):void {

    var entierSaisi:String;
    var entier:int;

    entierSaisi = (txtEntier.text);
    entier = int(entierSaisi);

    entier = mesEntiers.indexOf(entier);

    if (entier != -1) {
        for (var i = entier; i < mesEntiers.length; i++) {
            entier[i] = entier[i + 1];
        }
        mesEntiers.pop();
    }

}
```

Of course, I try just to remove errors mentioned in your question, and not improve your function.

Hope that can help.

Comment: It fixed two of the errors but I still get    1061: Call for indexOf method might not be defined via the static int type reference at entier = (entier.indexOf(entierSaisi));

Comment: @AndréEthier Did you see my code ? it's : `entier = mesEntiers.indexOf(entier);` and not `entier = (entier.indexOf(entierSaisi));`, the array is `mesEntiers`.

Comment: I did see it but I guess i forgot to copy it. Thanks!